# How to do a simple length validation

Tags: python

```
numberofpasswords = int(input("Please input the number of usernames needed"))

for counter in range (0, numberofpasswords):

    password = str(input("Input the 3 letter password"))

    length = len(password)

    while  length > 3 and length < 3:
        print("please enter a 3 letter password")
        name = str(input("Please input the 3 letter password"))

    print("your password is", password)
```

Comment: What is your question?  Note that your `while` loop will _never_ run since `length > 3 and length < 3` always evaluates to `False` no matter what length is (it can't be both greater than _and_ less than 3)

Comment: `while  length > 3 and length < 3`....`while length!=3:`? You need to set password again inside of the while loop, and length

Comment: 3-letter password? Why bother?

Comment: `length > 3 and length < 3` can never be satisfied. You need `length != 3` or use `or`

Comment: @chepner much easier to debug with 3 letters than 512

Comment: @C.Nivs Apparently not, in this case.

Comment: Thanks guys !!!! you all helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following condition isn't correct

```
while length > 3 and length < 3:
```

because the value of the `length` variable will never be greater and smaller than `3` *at the same time*, so the `while` loop will never run.

It looks like you actually need to use the `or` operator

```
while length > 3 or length < 3:
```

which will be `True` if `length` is either greater or smaller than `3`.

Going further, I guess it would be even better to use the `!=` operator

```
while length != 3:
```

which means "while length isn't 3".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to have the user enter a 3-character password. Have you tried this approach?

```
numberofpasswords = int(input("Please input the number of usernames needed"))

for counter in range (0, numberofpasswords):

    password = str(input("Input the 3 letter password"))

    length = len(password)

    while  length != 3:
        print("please enter a 3 letter password")
        password = str(input("Please input the 3 letter password"))
        length = len(password)

    print("your password is",password)
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I can help :)